# Why this code is giving ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ConcurrentHashMapTest {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

            Map<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            hMap.put("FIRST", "1");
            hMap.put("SECOND", "2");
            hMap.put("THIRD", "3");
            hMap.put("FOURTH", "4");
            hMap.put("FIFTH", "5");
            hMap.put("SIXTH", "6");
            System.out.println("HashMap before iteration : " + hMap);
            Iterator<String> hashMapIterator = hMap.keySet().iterator();

            while (hashMapIterator.hasNext()) {
                  String key = hashMapIterator.next();
                  if (key.equals("FOURTH")){
                       hMap.put(key + "-SHIVAM", "I AM NEW KEY IN HMAP");
            }
            } 
            System.out.println("HashMap after iteration : " + hMap);
      }
}
```

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
>   at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
>   at ConcurrentHashMapTest.main(ConcurrentHashMapTest.java:21)
> ```

I am wondering why this exception is coming. The exception is not at all seems to be fair in this case.

Comment: You're modifying the map while you're iterating through its elements. Also, since you're using a `Map`, you could just use `if hMap.containsKey("FOURTH")) { /* code */ }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not allowed to modify a collection or map while iterating over it (except for the `Iterator.remove()` method), because it is unclear how the modification should affect the iteration. Instead store the keys and values to add in a separate map and then use [`putAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putAll%28java.util.Map%29) after the loop.

---

*Example 1:* putting entries

```
Map<String, String> map = /* ... */;
Map<String, String> mapToPut = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String key = iterator.next();
  if (key.equals("Test")) {
    mapToPut.put("New key for " + key, "new value");
  }
}
map.putAll(mapToPut);
```

*Example 2:* removing entries

```
Map<String, String> map = /* ... */;
Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String key = iterator.next();
  if (key.equals("Test")) {
    iterator.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: agree!!! but is it in docs???

Comment: Yes. For [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), the class documentation says: *… if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a 'ConcurrentModificationException'.‘

Comment: Minor correction, you actually *can* modify the collection while iterating  it - but you have to use the iterator to do the modification - for example, if the iterator supports `remove()` - you can remove elements while iterating. ConcurrentModificationException happens only when you try to modify the collection NOT with the iterator you're using to iterate it.

Comment: can i get piece of code for above stmt..if possible

Comment: I added examples for both putting and removing entries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-list-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-removing   the ans which has 20 likes ...if you go through that..then its says even in remove we get exception..is nt it??

Comment: This only applies to `HashMap.remove`, not to `Iterator.remove`.

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentModificationException is because you are modifying the collection while iterating it.

You can change the logic something as below to avoid it

```
   Map<String, String> hMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hMap.put("FIRST", "1");
                            hMap.put("SECOND", "2");
                            hMap.put("THIRD", "3");
                            hMap.put("FOURTH", "4");
                            hMap.put("FIFTH", "5");
                            hMap.put("SIXTH", "6");
                            System.out.println("HashMap before iteration : " + hMap);
                            Iterator<String> hashMapIterator = hMap.keySet().iterator();
                            boolean isFourth =false;
                            while (hashMapIterator.hasNext()) {
                                  String key = hashMapIterator.next();
                                  if (key.equals("FOURTH")){
                                      isFourth=true; 

                            }
                            } 
                            if(isFourth)
                            hMap.put("FOURTH" + "-SHIVAM", "I AM NEW KEY IN HMAP");
                            System.out.println("HashMap after iteration : " + hMap);
```